# Using keywords in asp.net mvc3 views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, keyword, asp.net-mvc-views

I am using MVC3 framework to design a website. I pull the data in the controller from the ms sql database and one of the columns in the table is named as "do". When I try to create a view to display the information using the @Model keyword (eg: @Model.do) , I get an error:

Identifier expected; do is a keyword.

I want to know if there is a way to use the column names ( which are keywords in c#) in the MVC3 views or do I only have the choice of renaming the column in the database table ?

Thank You !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you use any keyword in C# is to prefix it with an '@'. For example, you'll see this a lot

```
@Html.ActionLink("My Link", "Action", null, new {@class="abc"})
```

to add "class" attribute to a "a" tag.  This is legitimate code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Entity e = new Entity();
        e.@do = 10;
    }
}

class Entity
{
    public int @do
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

and so is

```
public void DoSomething(int @do)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < @do; i++)
    {
        // process i
    }
}
```

If you are using ASPX as your view engine, the following is fine:

```
<%= Model.@do %>
```

In Razor view, the following is also valid:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.@do)
```

or

```
@(@Model.@do)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not a way to define the variable `do` inside of a viewmodel (.cs class).

```
"Error 1 Invalid token 'do' in class, struct, or interface member declaration"
```

That being said, you can remap in your model so that the column `do` is mapped to the field `do_field`

```
public class Entity
{
 [Column("do")]
 public string do_field { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Although I am using the Entity Framework model to access the database, I can still do remapping in it.

Comment: @Learner - That is correct. The model you define which is used by EF can have this data annotation in it. Or, you may use fluent api (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh295844(v=vs.103).aspx) to define the mapping.

Comment: @WernerStrydom - It is correct in that the error displayed for using a keyword is shown, and how to remap the entity is shown. I did not realize the `@` could be used as an escape property like that so the only incorrect statement here is more incomplete in that, as your answer states, you can escape keywords with the `@` symbol.

Comment: @TravisJ I think you gave good advice. My response was directed at your very first statement.

Comment: @WernerStrydom: I tried your suggestion of escaping the keywords and it works really good . Thank You for giving an alternative solution for the problem !!